# How is dimension of $V(g_1|_{x=0})$ same as $V(g_1) \cap V(x_1)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose I have $g_1, \ldots, g_t \in \mathbb{C}[x_1, ..., x_n]$.
Let 
$$
V_1=\{ \mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{C}^n : g_j(\mathbf{x}) = 0, 1 \leq j \leq t  \} \cap \{ \mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{C}^n : x_1 = 0 \}
$$
and 
$$
V_2 = \{ \mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{C}^{n-1} : g_j(0, \mathbf{y}) = 0, 1 \leq j \leq t \}.
$$
These two algebraic sets are basically the same... 
but how does one go about  to show that they have the same dimension? (as $V_1 \in \mathbb{A}^n$ and $V_2 \in \mathbb{A}^{n-1}$) Thank you very much.

Comment: $V_2=\{(0,\underline{y})\in\mathbb{C}^n\mid g_j(0,\underline{y})=0,\,1\leq j\leq t\}=V_1$. Is it clear?

Comment: Not quite... I see that your $V_2$ and $V_1$ have the same dimension in $\mathbb{A}^n$ but how does one show that this in fact equals the dimension of my $V_2$ in $\mathbb{A}^{n-1}$? (I'm sure there is a simple reason for this...)

Comment: Sorry for my previous wrong notations. In your $V_1$ the first coordinare $x_1$ is $0$, so $g(\underline{x})=g(0,\underline{y})$ for any $\underline{x}\in V_1$; then your $V_1$ and $V_2$ are regular isomorphic in a trivial way.

Comment: ahhh yes I think I got it now... thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. ;)